# How to use dynamic parameters in a sub-query in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to filter a query by a < date and based on this list records by customer number and branch.

In the query below I have the data filtered by the date and one particular customer number and branch. How can I run it to provide me all customer number and branches?

```
DECLARE @DateFilter date;
SET @DateFilter = '2019-12-16';

Select 
    C.No_,
    C.[Name], 
    LE.No_,
    LE.Branch,
    DLE.Amount
from 
    (   select distinct
            [Customer No_] as No_,
            [Global Dimension 1 Code] as Branch
        from [Cust_ Ledger Entry] 
        where 
            [posting date] < @DateFilter and
            [Open] = 1 
    ) LE Left Join  
    [Customer] C
    on C.No_ = LE.No_ left Join
    (
        Select 
            [Customer No_] as No_,
            [Initial Entry Global Dim_ 1] as Branch,
            sum(Amount) as Amount,
            sum([Amount (LCY)]) as [Amount (LCY)]   
        from [Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] DLE
        where  
            [posting date] < @DateFilter AND
            [Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] IN (
                select distinct [Entry No_] 
                FROM [Cust_ Ledger Entry] 
                where 
                    [Customer No_]  = '102348' and
                    [posting date] < @DateFilter and
                    [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'D--HE-001' and
                    [Open] = 1 
            )
        group by [Initial Entry Global Dim_ 1],[Customer No_]
    ) DLE on LE.No_ = DLE.No_ and LE.Branch = DLE.Branch 
Where 
C.No_ = '102348' and
LE.Branch = 'D--HE-001'
```

I tried creating joins like:

```
from
    [Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] DLE LEFT JOIN
    [Cust_ Ledger Entry] LE 
    on DLE.[Customer No_] = LE.[Customer No_] and DLE.[Initial Entry Global Dim_ 1] = LE.[Global Dimension 1 Code] left join
    [Customer] C
    on DLE.[Customer No_] = C.No_ 
where
     LE.[Customer No_] = '102348' and
     LE.[Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'D--HE-001' and
     LE.[posting date] < @DateFilter and
     DLE.[posting date] < @DateFilter
```

But this created multiple duplicate entries.

Is it possible to make a joins to avoid duplicates or a dynamic parameter to allow to run the query to display all records?

Comment: Huh? This doesn't make any sense at all. You have more than enough rep at SO to know you need to provide some details when asking questions.

Comment: General feedback as I don't want to spend time reading all this. Start from the inside out to troubleshoot. You also might want to use CTEs to help organize your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the IN with an JOIN in the LEFT JOIN to the following.

```
 left Join
    (
        Select 
            [Customer No_] as No_,
            [Initial Entry Global Dim_ 1] as Branch,
            sum(Amount) as Amount,
            sum([Amount (LCY)]) as [Amount (LCY)]   
        from [Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] DLE
        INNER JOIN (
            select distinct [Customer No_],[Entry No_] 
            FROM [Cust_ Ledger Entry] 
            where 
                [posting date] < @DateFilter and
                [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'D--HE-001' and
                [Open] = 1 
            ) CLE
        ON DLE.[Customer No_] = CLE.[Customer No_]
        and DLE.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] = CLE.[Entry No_]  
        where  
            DLE.[posting date] < @DateFilter AND
        group by DLE.[Initial Entry Global Dim_ 1],DLE.[Customer No_]
    ) DLE on LE.No_ = DLE.No_ and LE.Branch = DLE.Branch
```

The query can be further optimized knowing the table structures.